# Keyboard shortcuts with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard-shortcuts

How can I wire an event to fire if someone presses the letter <kbd>g</kbd>?

(Where is the character map for all the letters BTW?)

Comment: Character map for all the letters on this classy site: http://rmhh.co.uk/ascii.html

Comment: Another useful site for key codes is http://keycode.info

Answer (score 144):

Since this question was originally asked, John Resig (the primary author of jQuery) has forked and improved the js-hotkeys project. His version is available at:

http://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys

Comment: It supports the `meta` key, something that is not supported in the `js-hotkeys` :) Thanks

Comment: He has a Nuget package, so I went with this one.

Comment: I must say, it's very good for key-combinations (especially those special keys like shift,ctrl,alt,...) but I'm having troubles with basic mapping 0-9 and a-z).

Comment: This answer does give useful links.  Could you also answer the original question?  E.g. "how can I wire an event to fire if someone presses the letter g"?  The jquery.hotkeys module has some documentation, which I'm sure is great if you already know what you're doing...but for those of us trying to hack something together, an answer to the original question would be great.

Comment: How do you prevent the default bubbling up to the browser? Nothing mentioned on the readme from what I see.

Answer (score 87):

What about [jQuery Hotkeys](https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys)?

> jQuery Hotkeys lets you watch for keyboard events anywhere in your code supporting almost any key combination.

To bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to a function (`f`), for example:

```
$(document).bind('keydown', 'ctrl+c', f);
```

Comment: WOW...that's probably the easiest plugin I've ever used!

Comment: working with this out of the box it does not prevent browser defaults. So Ctrl+n will open a new tab in the browser for instance.  There is no access to the event object so not sure how to preventDefault with this.

Comment: @Gurnard We probably shouldn't be preventing user defaults, except in rare cases where it has been communicated to the user in advance and they are expecting that behavior within the web app (and maybe provide a setting for them to change it)... otherwise it's incredibly annoying. **Example 1**: When composing a post on Stack Exchange and instead of hiding the browser, *Cmd H* makes `## Heading ##` appear in the text field. **Example 2**: [This question.](https://superuser.com/questions/1269148/) **Example 3**: [This Q&A](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/3781/).

Comment: @Mentalist  I appreciate the UX comment but it does not apply in our current situation. I just want to be able to do this technically the architectural and UX decisions would be another post :-)

Answer (score 45):

I recently wrote a standalone library for this.  It does not require jQuery, but you can use it with jQuery no problem.  It's called Mousetrap.

You can check it out at http://craig.is/killing/mice

Comment: This is very nice. I really appreciate the support for handling of sequence of keys.

Comment: I am using Moustrap and find it much better thet HotKeys plugin. Very recommended. @Crag thanks for the good work.

Comment: I liked the documentation as well as the way to prevent default behavior of the elements. This library should be on NuGet.

Comment: Agreed. This is superior. jquery.hotkey wasn't incorrectly firing when a textarea had focus for me, but this didn't. Also it's better in all the ways previous commenters mention.

Answer (score 25):

Well there are many ways. But I am guessing you are interested in an advanced 
implementation. Few days back I was in same search, and I found one.

[Here.](http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/)

It's good for capturing events from keyboard and you will find the character maps too.
And good thing is ... it's jQuery. Check the demo on same page and decide.

An alternative library is [here](http://www.west-wind.com/WestwindWebToolkit/samples/Ajax/html5andCss3/keycodechecker.aspx).

Comment: Just to make it clear, it works perfectly without jquery too.

Answer (score 17):

If you want just simple shortcuts (like 1 letter, for example just <kbd>g</kbd>) you could easily do it without a extra plugin:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if(e.charCode == 103) {
    // Your Code
  }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work in IE9. In IE, something like this works:
        e = e || window.event;
        var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

Answer (score 16):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#test").keypress(function(e){
                if (e.which == 103) 
                {
                    alert('g'); 
                };
            });
        });
    </script>

    <input type="text" id="test" />
```

[this site says 71 = g but the jQuery code above thought otherwise](http://www.webonweboff.com/tips/js/event_key_codes.aspx)

*Capital G = 71*, lowercase is 103

Comment: Use this! if (e.which == 103 || e.keyCode == 103 || window.event.keyCode == 103)

Comment: This only happends when you are focussed on the text field

Comment: The link is dead :(

Answer (score 9):

You could also try the [shortKeys](https://github.com/riklomas/shortkeys) jQuery plugin. Usage example:

```
$(document).shortkeys({
  'g': function () { alert('g'); }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

After studying some jQuery at Codeacademy I found a solution to bind a key with the animate property. The whole idea was to animate without scrolling to jump from one section to another. The example from Codeacademy was to move Mario through the DOM but I applied this for my website sections (CSS with 100% height). Here is a part of the code:

```
$(document).keydown(function(key) {
    switch(parseInt(key.which, 10)) {
        case 39:
            $('section').animate({top: "-=100%"}, 2000);
            break;
        case 37:
            $('section').animate({top: "+=100%"}, 2000);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
});
```

I think you could use this for any letter and property.

Source: http://www.codecademy.com/forum_questions/50e85b2714bd580ab300527e

Answer (score 3):

The following simple command can activate the ctrl + s key:

```js
$(document).keydown(function (event) {
    if (event.ctrlKey && event.which === 83) {
        alert("Ctrl+S");
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Note: The jQuery Hotkeys plugin does not work properly

Answer (score 1):

There is a new version of hotKeys.js that works with 1.10+ version of jQuery.   It is small, 100 line javascript file. 4kb or just 2kb minified.  Here are some Simple usage examples are :

```
$('#myBody').hotKey({ key: 'c', modifier: 'alt' }, doSomething);

$('#myBody').hotKey({ key: 'f4' }, doSomethingElse);

$('#myBody').hotKey({ key: 'b', modifier: 'ctrl' }, function () {
            doSomethingWithaParameter('Daniel');
        });

$('#myBody').hotKey({ key: 'd', modifier :'shift' }, doSomethingCool);
```

Clone the repo from github : https://github.com/realdanielbyrne/HoyKeys.git
or go to the github repo page https://github.com/realdanielbyrne/HoyKeys or fork and contribute.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @craig, I recently built a shortcut library.

https://github.com/blainekasten/shortcut.js

Chainable API with support for multple functions bound to one shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

## I have made you the key press! Here is my code:

```html
<h1>Click inside box and press the g key! </h1>
 <script src="https://antimalwareprogram.co/shortcuts.js"> </script>
<script>

 shortcut.add("g",function() {
 alert("Here Is Your event! Note the g in ths code can be anything ex: ctrl+g or F11 or alt+shift or alt+ctrl or 0+- or even esc or home, end keys as well as keys like ctrl+shift+esc");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I Was trying to do the exact same thing, I accomplished this after a long time! Here is the code I ended up using! It works: Perfect! This was Done by using the [shortcuts.js](http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/) library! added a few other key presses as an example!

**Just Run the code snip-it, Click inside box and press the <kbd>G</kbd> key!**

Note on the <kbd>ctrl+F</kbd> and <kbd>meta+F</kbd> that will disable all <kbd>keyboard shortcuts</kbd> so you have to make the keyboard shortcuts in that same script as well!
also the <kbd>keyboard shortcut</kbd> actions can only be called in `javascript`!

To convert html to `javascript`, `php`, or `ASP.net` go [here](http://www.yellowpipe.com/yis/tools/HTML_converter/)!
To see all my <kbd>keyboard shortcuts</kbd> in a live JSFIDDLE Click Here!

## Update

```
    <h1>Click inside box and press the <kbd>G</kbd> key! </h1>
     <script src="https://antimalwareprogram.co/shortcuts.js"> </script>
    <script>

     shortcut.add("g",function() {
        alert("Here Is Your event from the actual question! This Is where you replace the command here with your command!");
    });
shortcut.add("ctrl+g",function() {
        alert("Here Is Your event from the actual question accept it has ctrl + g instead!! This Is where you replace the command here with your command!");
shortcut.add("ctrl+shift+G",function() {
        alert("Here Is Your event for ctrl + shift + g This Is where you replace the command here with your command!");
    });
shortcut.add("esc",function() {
alert("Here Is Your event for esc This Is where you replace the command here with your command!");
    });
//Some MAC Commands
shortcut.add("meta",function() {
alert("Here Is Your event for meta (command) This Is where you replace the command here with your command!");
    });
shortcut.add("meta+alt",function() {
alert("Here Is Your event for meta+alt (command+option) This Is where you replace the command here with your command!");
    });
    </script>
shortcut.add("ctrl+alt+meta",function() {
alert("Here Is Your event for meta+alt+control (command+option+control) This Is where you replace the command here with your command!");
    });
//& =shift +7
shortcut.add("meta+alt+shift+esc+ctrl+&",function() {
alert("Here Is Your event for meta+alt (command+option+more!) This Is where you replace the command here with your command!");
    });
shortcut.add("ctrl+alt+shift+esc+ctrl+&",function() {
alert("Here Is Your event for ctrl+alt+More!!! This Is where you replace the command here with your command!");
    });
//Even try the F keys so on laptop it would be Fn plus the F key so in my case F5!
shortcut.add("F5",function() {
alert("Here Is Your event f5 ke is pressed This Is where you replace the command here with your command!");
    });
//Extra...My Favourite one: CTRL+F
<script>
//Windows

 shortcut.add("Ctrl+F",function() { //change to meta+F for mac!
    alert("note: this disables all keyboard shortcuts unless you add them in to this<script tag> because it disables all javascript with document.write!");

document.writeln(" <link href=\"https://docs.google.com/static/document/client/css/3164405079-KixCss_ltr.css\" type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\"> ");
document.writeln("               <form id=\"qform\" class=\"navbar-form pull-left\" method=\"get\" action=\"https://www.google.com/search\" role=\"search\"> "); 
document.writeln("  ");
document.writeln("  ");

document.writeln(" <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"domains\" value=\"https://antimalwareprogram.co\" checked=\"checked\"> "); 
document.writeln("              <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"sitesearch\" value=\"https://antimalwareprogram.co\" checked=\"checked\"> ");

document.writeln(" <div id=\"docs-findbar-id\" class=\"docs-ui-unprintable\"name=\"q\" type=\"submit\"><div class=\"docs-slidingdialog-wrapper\"><div class=\"docs-slidingdialog-holder\"><div class=\"docs-slidingdialog\" role=\"dialog\" tabindex=\"0\" style=\"margin-top: 0px;\"><div id=\"docs-slidingdialog-content\" class=\"docs-slidingdialog-content goog-inline-block\"><div class=\"docs-findbar-content\"><div id=\"docs-findbar-spinner\" style=\"display: none;\"><div class=\"docs-loading-animation\"><div class=\"docs-loading-animation-dot-1\"></div><div class=\"docs-loading-animation-dot-2\"></div><div class=\"docs-loading-animation-dot-3\"></div></div></div><div id=\"docs-findbar-input\" class=\"docs-findbar-input goog-inline-block\"><table cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" class=\"docs-findinput-container\"><tbody><tr><td class=\"docs-findinput-input-container\"><input aria-label=\"Find in document\" autocomplete=\"on\" type=\"text\" class=\"docs-findinput-input\" name=\"q\" type=\"submit\"  placeholder=\"Search Our Site\"></td><td class=\"docs-findinput-count-container\"><span class=\"docs-findinput-count\" role=\"region\" aria-live=\"assertive\" aria-atomic=\"true\"></span></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class=\"docs-offscreen\" id=\"docs-findbar-input-context\">Context:<div class=\"docs-textcontextcomponent-container\"></div></div><div role=\"button\" id=\"docs-findbar-button-previous\" class=\"goog-inline-block jfk-button jfk-button-standard jfk-button-narrow jfk-button-collapse-left jfk-button-collapse-right jfk-button-disabled\" aria-label=\"Previous\" aria-disabled=\"true\" style=\"user-select: none;\"><div class=\"docs-icon goog-inline-block \"><div class=\"\" aria-hidden=\"true\">&nbsp;</div></div></div><div role=\"button\" id=\"docs-findbar-button-next\" class=\"goog-inline-block jfk-button jfk-button-standard jfk-button-narrow jfk-button-collapse-left jfk-button-disabled\" aria-label=\"Next\" aria-disabled=\"true\" style=\"user-select: none;\"><div class=\"docs-icon goog-inline-block \"><div class=\"\" aria-hidden=\"true\">&nbsp;</div></div></div><div role=\"button\" id=\"\" class=\"goog-inline-block jfk-button jfk-button-standard jfk-button-narrow\" tabindex=\"0\" data-tooltip=\"More options\" aria-label=\"\" style=\"user-select: none;\"><div class=\"docs-icon goog-inline-block \"><div class=\"\" aria-hidden=\"true\">&nbsp;</div></div></div></div></div><div class=\"docs-slidingdialog-close-container goog-inline-block\"><div class=\"docs-slidingdialog-button-close goog-flat-button goog-inline-block\" aria-label=\"Close\" role=\"button\" aria-disabled=\"false\" tabindex=\"0\" style=\"user-select: none;\"><div class=\"goog-flat-button-outer-box goog-inline-block\"><div class=\"goog-flat-button-inner-box goog-inline-block\"><div class=\"docs-icon goog-inline-block \"><div class=\"\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></div></div></div></div></div></div></div><div tabindex=\"0\" style=\"position: absolute;\"></div></div></div></div> ");
document.writeln(" <a href=\"#\" onClick=\"window.location.reload();return false;\"></a> "); 
document.writeln("  ");
document.writeln("                </form> "); 
document.writeln("  ");
document.writeln(" <h1> Press esc key to cancel searching!</h1> ");
  document.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => event.preventDefault());


  shortcut.add("esc",function() {
    alert("Press ctrl+shift instead!");
  location.reload();

  
});
});
</script>
 
// put all your other keyboard shortcuts again below this line!

//Another Good one ...Ctrl+U Redirect to alternative view source! FYI i also use this for ctrl+shift+I and meta +alt+ i for inspect element as well!
  shortcut.add("meta+U",function() { 

            window.open('view-source:https://antimalwareprogram.co/pages.php', '_blank').document.location = "https://antimalwareprogram.co/view-source:antimalwareprogram.co-pages_php.source-javascript_page.js";
  });
 shortcut.add("ctrl+U",function() { 

            window.open('view-source:https://antimalwareprogram.co/pages.php', '_blank').document.location = "https://antimalwareprogram.co/view-source:antimalwareprogram.co-pages_php.source-javascript_page.js";
  });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it yourself, you should probably use the "key" property instead of "which" (i.e. which is deprecated):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key

```
$("body").on('keypress', function(e){
    if('g' === e.key){
        console.log("ok");
    }
});
```