# Creating a shortcut key for the letter j to redirect to a url using jquery

Tags: jquery, keyboard-shortcuts

Using jQuery (if it helps), I'd like to create a shortcut key for the letter <kbd>J</kbd>, 
so when someone clicks on the keyboard letter <kbd>J</kbd>, it redirects to a webpage.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is yes, this is possible.  See [Jquery Events Keypress](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/keypress)

If you want it to be a universal shortcut then simply bind

```
$(document).keypress(function(event) {
   if (event.which === 106) { window.location = 'your_url'; }
});
```

Remember to make it very clear to the users that this will happen.  There's nothing more off putting to a user than to accidentally trigger a command they didn't know existed.

Answer (score 2):

Based on this page here http://docs.jquery.com/Events/keypress

```
$().keypress(function (e)
{
   //74 == J
   //106 == j
   if (e.which == 74 || e.which == 106)
    {
         //redirect
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Already asked on SO, read this thread:

[Keyboard shortcuts with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593602/keyboard-shortcuts-with-jquery)

I think, that this answer is what you are looking for (it uses a jQuery plugin):

[Keyboard shortcuts with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593602/keyboard-shortcuts-with-jquery/1160131#1160131)