# Using accesskey in chrome triggers an "unauthenticated sources" warning

Tags: html, google-chrome, access-keys

When using the [`accesskey` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/accesskey) in chrome in order to create shortcuts on my website, it does not work because chrome says:

> This page is trying to load scripts from unauthenticated sources
>   (https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1342714?hl=en)

[image: the dialog]

When accepting unauthenticated sources in the top right corner it works, but I don't want my users to have to do this. Should I use [a javascript solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580814/creating-a-shortcut-key-for-the-letter-j-to-redirect-to-a-url-using-jquery) as a workaround? Is this a (chrome) bug?

```html
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com/html" accesskey="h">HTML tutorial</a><br>
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com/css" accesskey="c">CSS tutorial</a>
```

The demo uses the `c` and `h` keys

**edit**: It seems that this problem only exists while using a `href`, because this demo works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/qmB3R/

**I have decided to just use something [much better](https://craig.is/killing/mice) to handle this problem. I leave the question here in order for others to find and for attracting attention for a chrome developer to fix the issue.**

Comment: Instead of your last paragraph, why don't you write a self-answer where you show how to use that much better library. By no means only link to it because that answer will be considered Not an answer and probably deleted. To attract attention from Chrome developers: don't they have an issue tracker? I'm not sure how many, if any, follow these tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears this is because w3schools redirect the links without a trailing '/' insecurely to the version with '/'. In their [own example](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_global_accesskey) they also use the incorrect url which lead me to this confusion. So in short: **don't redirect insecure if you want to us accesskey**.