# How to detect Keyboard Combination with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want make alert, that will be run after user presses `Alt+F+U`.

How to make it with jquery?

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/593602/keyboard-shortcuts-with-jquery

Answer (score 3):

It is a nice jquery plugin for binding hotkey combinations:

```
$(document).bind('keydown', 'alt+f+u', fn);
```

[GitHub](https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jquery [js-hotkeys](https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys) plugin.
Example of usage :

```
$(document).bind('keydown', 'ctrl+c', fn);
```

Answer (score -3):

try the below

shortcut.add("Alt+F+U",function() {
    alert("Pressed!");
});