# run functionality of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button in HTML and I want to provide a shortcut key to it, which should run the functionality as when button clicks what happens.

Is it possible to do something like this using JavaScript or jQuery.

Comment: check this out

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/593602/keyboard-shortcuts-with-jquery

Comment: I think you can use Hotkeys. Using hotkeys you can add functionalities  like pressing Ctrl+S will submit form. I have found only this [link](https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys) for Hotkeys

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using plain HTML: `accesskey="x"`. Then you can use <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> (depending on the browser though if it's <kbd>alt</kbd> or something else)

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
$("body").keypress(function(event) {    
  if ( event.which == 13 ) { // put your own key code here    
     event.preventDefault();    
     $("#yourbutton").click();    
   }    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy using jQuery. To trigger a button:

```
$('#my-button').trigger('click');
```

To monitor for keypress:

```
$(window).keypress(function (event) {
    if (event.which === 13) { // key codes here: http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#my-button').trigger('click');
    }
});
```

Now, if you want to use the Ctrl key or similar you use

```
    if (event.which === 13 && event.ctrlKey)
```

and similar with `event.altKey`, `event.shiftKey`.

Comment: I didn't copy it from anywhere :P, It's just the best way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('keypress', function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode === youreKeyCodeHere) {
            // if (e.keyCode === youreKeyCodeHere && e.shiftKey === ture) { // shift + keyCode
            // if (e.keyCode === youreKeyCodeHere && e.altKey === ture) { // alt + keyCode
            // if (e.keyCode === youreKeyCodeHere && e.ctrlKey === ture) { // ctrl + keyCode
                $('youreElement').trigger('click');
            }
        });
```

Where `youreKeyCode` can be any of the following [javascript char codes](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes) , if you're shortcut needs an alt (shift, ctrl ...) use the commented if's . `youreElement` is the element that holds the click event you whant to fire up.