# Delete a dropped item by delete key press

Tags: jquery

I have created a page droppable and am trying to delete the dragged elements. But I have a problem that I don't know how delete the selected elements from the keyboard delete key.
here is my code:

```
$canvasElement.click(function() {
    jQuery('.canvas-element').removeClass('selectedItem');
    jQuery($canvasElement).addClass('selectedItem');
    jQuery('#button').removeClass('delete');
    jQuery('#button').addClass('showButton');
})

jQuery(".deleteButton").click(function () {
jQuery(".selectedItem").remove();
jQuery('#button').removeClass('showButton');
jQuery('#button').addClass('delete');
});
```

HTML:

```
<li>
    <p id="button" class="delete"><button class="deleteButton">Delete</button></p>
</li>
```

CSS:

```css
.selectedItem {
    border: 2px solid #5C3B84!important;
}
.showButton {
    display:block!important;
}
.delete {
    display:none;
}
```

But I have to delete the element from the keyboard delete key.

Comment: I don't fully understand your question. Do you want to do something when the user presses the delete key on the keyboard?
Then a simple keybinding should serve your needs.

Answer (score 0):

to delete using keyboard, you must have a plugin called `jquery.hotkeys`.

Read here [Keyboard shortcuts with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593602/keyboard-shortcuts-with-jquery) for your question.

Or, if you wish only javascript look into same page because there will appear other alternatives to do.