# Can I use keyboard short cuts to use my website

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am creating my website in asp.net 4 and would like to know if I can allow my user to use my website with his keyboard.

I want him to be allowed to have simple shortcuts similar to desktop applications such as saving with ctrl + s saves it.

I would want similar functionality in my website where he can maybe use shift + a and add a new product. shift + del to delete a product.

How can I achieve this ? With Jquery? does Asp.net provide an option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can achieve this with jquery or native javascript.

Similar question at [Keyboard shortcuts with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593602/keyboard-shortcuts-with-jquery)

And related project at https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys