# jquery : how to use keyboard shortcut F2 and F3

Tags: jquery, keypress

Good day,

Im wondering if we can use keyboard shortcut <kbd>F2</kbd> and <kbd>F3</kbd> to execute function. If got, maybe can share your code to me. Below my idea to make the shortcut key. i've tried but not functioning.

```
$("#ENQUIRY_VIEWMETER").keypress(function(event) {
    if(event.which == 113) { //F2
        updateMtr();
    } else if(event.which == 114) { //F3
        resetView();
    }
});
```

p/s : or maybe need some amendment on my code. :)

Comment: search before post [keyboard-shortcuts-with-jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/593602/keyboard-shortcuts-with-jquery)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try using the `keydown` event instead of `keypress`. The `keydown` event tells you which actual key was pressed, but `keypress` is more about what character resulted.

And return `false` so that the default browser behaviour (if any) for those keys doesn't go ahead (don't return `false` for other keys).

```
$("#ENQUIRY_VIEWMETER").keydown(function(event) {
    if(event.which == 113) { //F2
        updateMtr();
        return false;
    }
    else if(event.which == 114) { //F3
        resetView();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TTrPp/

Comment: Got it!!.. i knew it, its not that hard.. thx for the answer!!

Answer (score 2):

try like this

```
$(document).keypress(function(e){
   if(e.charCode == 97){
      alert("a");
      return false;
  }
 })
```

check this [jQuery HotKey plugin](http://code.google.com/p/js-hotkeys/)

Comment: OP wants to know how to test for function keys. `keypress` is the wrong way to do that (otherwise the code in the question would work).

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.onkeyup = KeyCheck;

function KeyCheck(e){

   var KeyID = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : e.keyCode;

   if(KeyID == 113){ 

      updateMtr();

   } else if(KeyID == 114) {

       resetView();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 