# Programmatically creating jQuery events for clicks with meta/control key held down

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to be able to programmatically create a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-click or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-click event, so that I could test my event-handling code, which looks like this:

```
// event is a jQuery event
if (event.metaKey || event.ctrlKey) {
    // do stuff
    openUrlInNewWindow(url);
} else {
    // do other stuff
    openUrl(this.clickedAd.url);
}
```

I'm calling the method with `$(selector).trigger('click', event)`. I've tried creating the event like this:

```
jQuery.Event("click", {metaKey: true, keyCode: 91});
```

but jQuery transforms the event I pass in and seems to strip out the `keyCode` and `metaKey` attributes, so when I receive it in my event handler `metaKey` is always `false`.

What's the right way of creating a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-click event?

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/593602/keyboard-shortcuts-with-jquery

Comment: Thanks, but my question isn't about *handling* events. It's about *generating* them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var e = jQuery.Event( "click", { keyCode: 91, ctrlKey: true } );

$(".selector").trigger(e);
```

that work?

have a jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/8n3u6/

Comment: Thank you! I was actually triggering the event incorrectly. I was doing `$(selector).trigger('click', myEvent)`. :/