# Assign function for lshift down in jquery and keydrown plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keydown, shift, keycode

I use the Keydrown plugin, so this works nicely with letter keys:

```
kd.W.down(function () {
    //...
});
```

How can I assign the same function to lshift instead of W? (I don't know how to put here a keycode instead of letter).

And if possible, how can I select 2 keycodes and do something for lshift+W? (when both are pressed at the same time).

**edit**:

Seems the best and the most simple way to select any key by keycode is to edit the plugin itself - to edit the keycode list under the KEY_MAP. For example add:

```
,'LSHIFT': 16
```

to the list, and call `kd.LSHIFT.down`.

The question about **lshift+W** still remains - is it possible to put the 2 keycodes under the 1 name in this KEY_MAP list? (would be the best / simplest solution)

Comment: You might want to try js-hotkeys this might be a good reference
   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/593602/keyboard-shortcuts-with-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the keydrown plugin edit the list under the KEY_MAP, for example add:

```
,'LSHIFT': 16
```

**LSHIFT+W** can be achieved in this way:

```
kd.W.press(function () {
    kd.LSHIFT.press(function () {
        //...
        console.log();
    });
    //optional...
    console.log();
});
kd.W.up(function () {
    kd.LSHIFT.press(function () {
        console.clear();
    });
    console.clear();
});
```

`down` can be used instead of `press` depending on desired behavior. To bind / unbind keys in more complex cases, use the [Keydrown plugin instructions](http://jeremyckahn.github.io/keydrown/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm the developer of Keydrown.  Sorry I didn't see this until now!  `kd.map.js` [supports the generic "shift" keycode](https://github.com/jeremyckahn/keydrown/blob/268c94b01bb62b5580b1bec968ced0a66d8e5de8/src/kd.map.js#L34) (`16`), but I'm not familiar with how that relates to the keycode for the left shift button specifically (somebody please feel free to chime in and clarify).

Anywho, if adding `'LSHIFT': 16` to the map works as desired, here's is what I'd recommend for achieving the "left shift + W" functionality:

```
kd.LSHIFT.down(function () {
  if (kd.W.isDown()) {
    // Your code here
  }
});
```

[`isDown`](http://jeremyckahn.github.io/keydrown/dist/doc/src/kd.key.js.html#isDown) is a newer Keydrown API that was introduced after this question was asked, I believe.

I hope this helps.  If the `LSHIFT` keycode works consistently across the [supported browsers](https://github.com/jeremyckahn/keydrown#browser-compatibility), please submit a [Pull Request](https://github.com/jeremyckahn/keydrown/pulls).