# Set accesskey to keyboard numeric pad keys with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

I'm developing a Web App with HTML5 and jQuery 1.10. I'm using the accesskey attribute in inputs and links to improve the navigation.

Actually I have this code:

```
    $("#linktabCost").attr("accesskey", "1");
    $("#linktabCapture").attr("accesskey", "2");
    $("#linktabInvoice").attr("accesskey", "3");
```

With this code, the accesskeys are working as follows:

[image]

My question is:

**How can I set the accesskey to the numbers of the keyboard numeric pad with jQuery?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue with the **shortcut.js** library and adding the numeric pad keys (97,98,99...) to the library **special_keys** array.

```
var special_keys = {
                'numpad_1': 97,
                'numpad_2': 98,
                'numpad_3': 99,
                'numpad_4': 100,
                'numpad_5': 101,
                'esc':27,
                'escape':27,
                'tab':9,
                'space':32,
                'return':13,
                'enter':13,
                'backspace':8
                 ...
}
```

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593602/keyboard-shortcuts-with-jquery) post to solve the problem